# async/await JavaScript with two functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am new to JavaScript, and I don't get how to deal with asynchronicity. I've been reading and tinkering for hours now, and I can't figure it out.

I have two functions that work beautifully when I run them independently in the console.... However, when I run them in sequence from the JS file, the second function runs before it has output from the first. I've read everything I can on async/await for javascript, and I can't figure out what I need to do to get the first function to run completely before the second starts to run. Also, the examples online just are not making sense to me. If you can help me that would be great.

The first function simply rolls six dice. The second function takes the output of this function and draws the rolls on the screen for the user to see.

How do I get them to run synchronically (function 1 first and function 2 second)?

```
function diceRoll(purchased) {
    DiceResults = []

    for (var i = 0; i < purchased; i++) {
        DiceResults.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    }
    return DiceResults
}

function DiceRolling(DiceResults) {
    await diceRoll();
    for (var i in DiceResults) {
        Q = (DiceResults[i])
        var x = document.createElement("IMG");
        x.setAttribute("src", Q + ".png");
        x.setAttribute("width", "304");
        x.setAttribute("height", "228");
        document.body.appendChild(x);
    }
}

diceRoll(5)
DiceRolling(DiceResults)
```

Comment: `diceRoll` isn't asynchronous, you don't need to use `await`.

Comment: The function you call with `await` either has to return a Promise or be defined with `async function` (that makes it automatically return a Promise).

Comment: Assuming you don't really need `await`/`async` and just want to call functions: remove `diceRoll(5)`, replace `DiceRolling(DiceResults)` with `DiceRolling()` in two places, replace `await diceRoll();` with `DiceResults = diceRoll();`.

Comment: *the second function runs before it has output from the first*. No, it doesn't.

Comment: So, I see the error of my question.... This wasn't the problem coding areas. I have two other functions that were not included that  are supposed to finish running before this one runs.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I try to ask another question that doesn't suck...

Comment: Yes, We need to store the result and pass to other function, good you got it already

Answer (score 1):

You're getting confused as to the purpose of async/await. This is for dealing with asynchronous requests to external resources. It's not necessary in your example as everything's happening internally. Changing your example like so:

```js
function diceRoll(purchased) {
    DiceResults = []

    for (var i = 0; i < purchased; i++) {
        DiceResults.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    }
    return DiceResults
}

function DiceRolling(DiceResults) {
    for (var i in DiceResults) {
        Q = (DiceResults[i])
        var x = document.createElement("IMG");
        x.setAttribute("src", Q + ".png");
        x.setAttribute("width", "304");
        x.setAttribute("height", "228");
        document.body.appendChild(x);
    }
}

var results = diceRoll(5)
DiceRolling(results)
```

does what you're after.
The result of the first function get passed to the second.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing asynchronous here, you don't need to use `await`.

You need to assign the result of calling `diceRoll()` to the `DiceResults` variable.

You should also declare variables local within functions.

```
function diceRoll(purchased) {
    var DiceResults = []

    for (var i = 0; i < purchased; i++) {
        DiceResults.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    }
    return DiceResults
}

function DiceRolling(DiceResults) {
    for (var i in DiceResults) {
        Q = (DiceResults[i])
        var x = document.createElement("IMG");
        x.setAttribute("src", Q + ".png");
        x.setAttribute("width", "304");
        x.setAttribute("height", "228");
        document.body.appendChild(x);
    }
}

DiceResults = diceRoll(5)
DiceRolling(DiceResults)
```